# Not able to fix Uncategorized (Xcode): Scheme Runner is not currently configured for the build action. issue in VS Code

Tags: flutter, xcode, visual-studio-code

I was running main.dart without any problems until I published app in App Store connect.
Now I have following error:
Uncategorized (Xcode): Scheme Runner is not currently configured for the build action.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14.

I run flutter doctor and it didn't show anything

```
    changers % flutter doctor
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.13.0-19.0.pre.5, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin- 
    arm64, locale
    en-SE)
    [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    [✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    [✓] VS Code (version 1.72.2)
    [✓] Connected device (3 available)
    [✓] Network resources

    • No issues found!
```

I also checked schema settings and it is shared

[image]

So I run out of ideas, what could be a reason for this issue. Thanks for any help!